# How to Add Groups from Project to Area in TFS using API?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I'm making a console application that takes user input to create a new area. Based on that name, groups are generated and put into the project, hard-coded into the application. As of now, the code below will do that:

```
Project that all areas will be placed into
    -> Areas
        -> New area just created
    -> Security
        -> Groups
            -> Newly created groups
```

However, I would also like those groups to be placed into the area itself:

```
Project that all areas will be placed into
    -> Areas
        -> New area just created
            -> Security
                -> Groups
                    -> Newly created groups
    -> Security
        -> Groups
            -> Newly created groups
```

Right now, when you view the *Security* of the area, there are only the Default groups in it, not the ones that I've created.

I can't find anything on managing the security for an area via API.

```
public class AreaBuilder
    {
        static IIdentityManagementService _ims;
        static List<TeamFoundationIdentity> m_groups = new List<TeamFoundationIdentity>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string projectName = "some_project";
            string mainUri = "http://something:8080/tfs";
            string collectionUri = "http://something:8080/tfs/some_collection";

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of an area that you'd like to create: \n\n");
            Console.Write("AreaBuilder> ");
            string areaName = Console.ReadLine();

            // Get the structure of the groups and their privileges
            AreaStructure structure = new AreaStructure(areaName);
            Dictionary<string, List<AreaStructure.Privileges>> groups = structure.getGroups();

            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(collectionUri));
            VersionControlServer vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            try
            {
                Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.TeamProject project = vcs.GetTeamProject(projectName);
                IGroupSecurityService gss = tpc.GetService<IGroupSecurityService>();

                foreach(string groupName in groups.Keys)
                {
                    gss.CreateApplicationGroup(project.ArtifactUri.AbsoluteUri, groupName, null);
                    Console.WriteLine(groupName + " created.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not create group: " + e.ToString());
            }

            WorkItemClassificationNode node = new WorkItemClassificationNode()
            {
                Name = areaName,
                StructureType = TreeNodeStructureType.Area,
                Children = new List<WorkItemClassificationNode>()
            };

            // Get the connection
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), new VssCredentials());

            // Get the work item client
            WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingClient = connection.
                GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

            // Create the new area
            WorkItemClassificationNode area = workItemTrackingClient.CreateOrUpdateClassificationNodeAsync(
                node,
                projectName,
                TreeStructureGroup.Areas).Result;

            // Get the project client
            ProjectHttpClient projectClient = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();

            // Get the projects in the project client
            IEnumerable<TeamProjectReference> projects = projectClient.GetProjects().Result;

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want to add your newly created group to the newly created Area Security dialog programmatically, and then grant permissions for that group.

Unfortunately there is no TFS ADK available now for you to add groups to the Area Security dialog programmatically. However, why do you want to add your new created group to that Project Security dialog first and then grant permissions for it? It is also possible for you to **grant permission directly** even though that group is not shown on the Area Security dialog.

You can have `TFSSecurity` command line to do the work for you or just use TFS API to grant the permission. Use the [IGroupSecurityService interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb169249.aspx).

This blog post also shows you how to use the API: [TFS SDK Get Groups Users Permissions using TFS API](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/262673/TFS-SDK-Get-Groups-Users-Permissions-using-TFS-API) . You could also take a look at this sample shows how to set permissions for Areas: [Set Security For Area/Iteration](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2009/02/03/tfs-api-part-12-set-security-for-areaiteration/)

Comment: also, to set permissions for groups, you have to pass an int corresponding to the permission you are trying to allow/deny. However, in the [TeamProjectPermissions Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.common.teamprojectpermissions(v=vs.120).aspx) they are missing an integer corresponding to the permissions of _Create Tag Definition_, _Delete Work Items In This Project_, and _Permanently Delete Work Items In This Project_. So I do not know how to set these permissions to a group within a project

Comment: @JoshEvans Sorry for the misunderstanding first. Have updated my reply.

Comment: thank you Patrick, great links. However, have you noticed my issue in my above comment?

Comment: @JoshEvans Haven't noticed this before. Not sure about this, you could take a look at TracyZhang's answer in this question https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ffc32977-63d7-4c8f-b64f-d8d069248399/how-to-set-team-project-security-via-tfs-api?forum=tfsadmin , seems you could get integer variable from the  corresponding database.

Comment: Haven't been able to set permissions at the area level for a group yet. I read the blog you linked to, and it seems some of the classes [Shai's blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2009/02/03/tfs-api-part-12-set-security-for-areaiteration/) was referring to are now obsolete. I also took a look at the [IGroupSecurityService interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb169249.aspx) and it appears that this is now obsolete. There are no answers anywhere in the past 5 years on how to set area-level permissions for a group in TFS using the API.